# MariaDB creates unnecessary temp files after upload data into table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

MariaDB version 10.3.

MariaDB creates unnecessary temp files like "0.00000n" while I upload huge file to database. How to automatically remove these files or not add to folder at all?

[image]

With MySQL 5.7 the same operations worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

These files aren't temporary files and they aren't unnecessary. These are binary logs which are used for replication (but also can be used for data recovery).

The filename `0` indicates, that you tried to disable this option in your configuration file by specifying `log-bin=0`.
This doesn't disable the option but uses the filename `0.*` instead.

To disable this option remove this entry (or add a comment in front of it).

Comment: Smells like binlogs.  What is the value of `purge_logs_days`?

Comment: @RickJames: I assume your first comment belongs to another question?! Yes, these are binlogs - file size is a little bit less than 1GB (max_binlog_size).

Comment: At first I was thinking about the odd filenames used by InnoDB's FULLTEXT.  Then I saw the link suggesting `log-bin=0` causes them.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help someone to save time. It's not easy to find answer by standard requests like "MariaDB creates huge temp files|MariaDB temp zero files" etc.

Just comment the line in MariaDB settings to disable binary logging:

```
#log-bin = mysql-bin
```

More detail there: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45474/huge-0-000001-and-0-000002-files-and-so-on-in-mysql-data-folder